# Proving an inequality which contains exponentials

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $x, y \in [0, 1]$ and $t > 0$.
I would like to show that
$$e^{\frac{-x+y-1}{t}} + 1 \ge e^{\frac{-(1-x)(1-y)}{t}} + 2 e^{\frac{-x}{t}}.$$

First of all I decided to rewrite terms above using Taylor's expansion.

$$1 - x + y - 1 + 1 \ge -(1 - x)(1-y) + 2(1 - x) \tag{TE}.$$
$$-x + y -1 \ge -(xy -x -y+1) - 2x$$
$$xy \ge 0$$
It's not hard to verify that $(\text{TE})$ stands for $x, y \in [0, 1]$ (in fact it stands for all $x, y \ge 0$) and $t >0$.

I suppose it isn't enough however. How can I finish my proof?

Answer (score 1):

Your inequality cannot be proved because it doesn't hold. Let $t=1$ and take $x=1,y=1$. Then your inequality says that $e^{-1}+1\geq1+ 2e^{-1}$, or equivalently $1\geq 2$.

Comment: Thanks. That's a sad information for me :(